# Site does not show review structured data in search listings

Tags: google-search, schema.org, google-search-console, microdata, structured-data

I have created a site using the Google Structured Data markup in order to make it output as a "review" in the search listings.

For example, this is the HTML for the page:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Review"> 
<span class="info-text">Pattern: <a href="http://amzn.to/1uKQOSs" target="_blank"><span class="pattern-author" itemprop="itemreviewed">Simplicity 2648</span></a></span>
    <p class="info-description">"<span itemprop="description"><em>The &quot;Amazing Fit&quot; dresses are quite promising, but I still needed adjustments, so it didn&#039;t make a huge difference. This pattern is well drafted though, and the result is great."</em></span></p>
    <span style="display:none;" itemprop="reviewer">Francesca Haselden          </span>
    <time itemprop="dtreviewed" datetime="2014-03-18">Tue 18 Mar</time>
    <span style="display:none;" itemprop="rating">4</span>
</div>
```

As you can see I have included the `itemprop` attribute with the following data:

- itemreviewed
- description
- reviewer
- dtreviewed
- rating

When I put the code above through the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) it validates correctly and shows me all the info it has gathered, correctly.

But when I perform a search for my search term, although I show up on the second page for listings, there is no review. No star rating etc. It does not present itself the same way I am seeing other structured data reviews showing on Google.

The above code has been live on my site for 6 weeks and according to webmaster tools has been crawled several times, so I can't see it being an issue with taking time to re-crawl the structured data.

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that Google does not trust this information enough to display it in search results. The more Google trusts a website, the more it is likely to show such information.

Another explanation is that Google thinks it is not interesting for users to display such information in search results.

Unfortunately, you can't control what Google displays in search results. If you believe there is bug, you can always open a thread in the Webmaster Forum.